# Python regex - bounded word

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to use a regex to identify a word between two characters and I just cannot succeed. This is my code:

```
re.match(r"\s*\#?\w*(\<)+\s*(?P<method>\w+)\s*(\>)+\w*", "# This <foo> truc")
```

The sentence has (or not) a python comment (#) and must show the group method.

Thank you for you time and help

Comment: [Try this](https://regex101.com/r/vBEM5I/1/)

Comment: Very nice app!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your regex to include optional spaces before `This` and `<`, then you can use the `groups` attribute:

```py
some_match = re.match(r"\s*\#?\s*\w*\s*(\<)+\s*(?P<method>\w+)\s*(\>)+\w*", "# This <foo> truc")

some_match.groups()
('<', 'foo', '>')

some_match.groups(1)
'foo'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works perfectly. However, one question: Aren't white spaces included in \w* ?

Comment: @linksse no, whitespaces are `\s` which includes `\n \t \r \s` which are newline, tab, carriage return, and space, respectively. `\w` is a word char (think `[A-Za-z]`)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some whitespace matches. After the `#` character, before the `<`, and after the `>`.

So one option is to add the missing whitespace matches:

```
>>> m = re.match(r"\s*\#?\s*\w*\s*(\<)+\s*(?P<method>\w+)\s*(\>)+\s*\w*", "# This <foo> truc")
>>> m.group('method')
'foo'
```

However, if you only need the value between `<` and `>`, then use `re.search` instead and you can simply your regex significantly:

```
>>> r = re.search(r"\<(?P<method>[^\>]*)\>", "# This <foo> truc")
>>> r.group('method')
'foo'
```